# Recursive function crashing in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, binary-tree

After trying to call a simple program to test my method for finding the 1st smaller node than the one given as a parameter:

```
BinaryTreeMap <int, int> m;
m[5] = 5;
m[3] = 3;
m[8] = 8;
m[1] = 1;
m[2] = 2;
m[6] = 6;
cout << m.firstSmaller(5) << " ";
cout<< m.firstSmaller(6);
cout << " " << m.firstSmaller(3) << " ";
cout << m.firstSmaller(12);
```

...my program just collapses, no errors, nothing. I pressume I am making some kind of an infinite loop by not exiting the recursive function correctly. But I don't know where, since when I try go by my method on a piece of paper, I get the correct result.

Here is the method:

```
template <typename TipKey,typename TipValue>
TypeValue BinaryTreeMap<TipKey,TipValue>::firstSmaller(TypeKey key)
{
BSNode *pom = functionforFirstSmaller(root, key);
if(pom == 0) throw "There is no key smaller than the given one!";
return pom->value;
}
```

And the functionforFirstSmaller:

```
BSNode* functionforFirstSmaller(BSNode *c, TypeKey k)
{
    if(c->left == 0 && c->right == 0) return c;
    if(c == 0) return 0;
    if(c->key >= k) return functionforFirstSmaller(c->left, k);
    BSNode *cvor = functionforFirstSmaller(c->right, k);
    //if(cvor == 0) return 0;
    return cvor;
}
```

I don't understand why it's crashing. If you guys could help me to understand, I would really appreciate it, since it would help me in my further on programming.
Sorry if it's not good explained, getting used to the English vocabulary in C++(not my native language).

Comment: What is root in firstSmaller()?

Comment: Root is the root of the whole binary tree. If the key I'm looking for smaller than it, it should be in the left SubTree.

Comment: try printing some output inside your recursive function.  It will help you identify when it fails

Comment: Is it possible that `c == 0` ? Since it's a pointer it looks weird to me. Same for `pom == 0`

Comment: It seems that when c=3 and then tries to call functionforFirstSmaller(3->right, k), 3->right is actually null , but still, didn't I take care of that problem in those first 2 ifs ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have inverted two lines of code. try:

```
BSNode* functionforFirstSmaller(BSNode *c, TypeKey k)
{
    if (c == 0) return 0;
    if (c->left == 0 && c->right == 0) return c;
    if (c->key >= k) return functionforFirstSmaller(c->left, k);
    BSNode *cvor = functionforFirstSmaller(c->right, k);
    return cvor;
}
```

Comment: Still crashing, but thank you for the answer. I believe I'm making some mistakes by trying to get to null pointers. That must be it. Will try to fix it now.